# java program using sax parser

Tags: java, parsing, sax

```
<z:row ows_team="india" ows_code="1121" ows_Response="president" ows_SubFunction="finance" ows_Plant="teamindia" ows_tenure="2years" ></z:row >
```

can i read xml of the above format using sax parser? and how?

Comment: <z:row ows_team="india" ows_code="1121" ows_Response="president" ows_SubFunction="finance" ows_Plant="teamindia" ows_tenure="2years" ></z:row >

Answer (score 1):

I just google and find -> [How to read XML file in Java – (SAX Parser)](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/)

Comment: hi hilal...it will work for the format <nn> <dd>myname</dd></nn>...but not the format that i have given...